# problems with plain asp.net default template

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

today i found something weird behavior of asp.net default website template.

I tried to add logo to the master page(i.e., Site.Master)

```
<div class="title">
            <h1>
            <img id="logoImage" src="images/headerlogo.png" /><span id="headerUser">heidi jones</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
```

Its working for `default.aspx` age and `about.aspx` page, but when i go to login page the logo image is not showing there.

Did i miss something? this is the first time im using asp.net default template...

Fallowing are screens

### Default.aspx Page

[image: Default.aspx Page]

### Login.aspx page

[image: Login.aspx Page]

### Working Code

```
<img id="logoImage" runat="server" src="~/images/headerlogo.png" /><span id="headerUser">heidi jones</span>
```

`I miss runat tag`

Comment: with each screen shot, post the image url for the logo

Comment: problem will solve if we use runat="server" for img tag and use `~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is being loaded from a relative url - so your root folder pages work, but not in sub folders use `~` at the start of the url in any image controls (don't forget `runat='server'`)

The tilde (~) character represents the root directory of the application in ASP.NET.

This is a relative path:

```
<img id="logoImage" src="images/smallprof.png">
```

It means that the browser will look for the image RELATIVE to the url of the current page - i.e. in the root folder it will look for /images/ in the security folder it will look for /security/windows

This is an absolute path

```
<img id="logoImage" src="/images/smallprof.png">
```

The browser will always look for /images/ regardless of the url of the page

Use the absolute path

Comment: Im adding image to master page, master page is in `root` folder only and images are in `images` folder in `root`

Comment: did you even try it? it doesn't matter where your master page is - it's the browser that's trying to load the image.

Comment: view-source and compare what the browser sees

Comment: the `img` code is exactly same for both the pages. `<img id="logoImage" src="images/smallprof.png">`

Comment: Hey if add `~` both pages not displaying logo

Comment: The `~` requires a `runat='server'` - but forget about that just put `<img id="logoImage" src="/images/smallprof.png">` on your page if you have the image in the `http://w.ebsi.te/images/` folder

Comment: Hey its working now we have to use like this `/<projectrootfolder>/images/smallprof.png`

Comment: You didn't say that your site was not hosted in the root folder of the web server.

Comment: im running my site locally using vs builtin server